# Install a package without updating other unrelated packages (Julia 1.0)

Tags: julia

It is possible to install a package in Julia 1.0 without updating other packages? For instance if a install `ClusterManagers`, the package `IJulia` (among others) gets updated. The package `ClusterManagers` has no dependencies.

```
(v1.0) pkg> add ClusterManagers
 Resolving package versions...
 Installed IJulia ───────────── v1.12.0
 Installed ClusterManagers ──── v0.3.2
 Installed ColorTypes ───────── v0.7.5
 Installed OrderedCollections ─ v1.0.1
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Project.toml`
  [34f1f09b] + ClusterManagers v0.3.2
  [7073ff75] ↑ IJulia v1.11.1 ⇒ v1.12.0
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Manifest.toml`
  [34f1f09b] + ClusterManagers v0.3.2
  [3da002f7] ↑ ColorTypes v0.7.4 ⇒ v0.7.5
  [7073ff75] ↑ IJulia v1.11.1 ⇒ v1.12.0
  [bac558e1] ↑ OrderedCollections v1.0.0 ⇒ v1.0.1
  Building IJulia → `~/.julia/packages/IJulia/4VL8h/deps/build.log`
```

I use Julia 1.0.0 (official https://julialang.org/ release) on Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the intention is that adding a package should not update the other ones. This is a bug (https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/issues/607) that has been fixed (https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/pull/642) and will be included in Julia v1.0.1.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

On Julia 1.4 and greater, you have [much finer control](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/api/#Pkg.add) over how dependencies get updated when adding new packages to a project.  The REPL mode makes this very easy to do, e.g.,

```
(Project) pkg> add --preserve=all Example
```

Using `--preserve=all` is the most conservative and may fail depending upon the requirements of the new package.  You can also give more latitude to the package manager by allowing just indirect dependencies to change version (`--preserve=direct`) or restrict direct dependencies to their non-breaking upgrades (`--preserve=semver`).